# Yii2 NavBar forcing load of extra Bootstrap

Tags: php, yii2

I'm attempting to adapt the Heroic Features template from [Start Bootstrap](https://startbootstrap.com/) to Yii2.

The `heroic-features.css` includes Bootstrap & I like to use CDNs where I can, so I've overridden `YiiAsset`, `JqueryAsset`, & `BootstrapAsset`.

Everything looks good until I include the NavBar.

In `frontend/views/layouts/main.php` I have everything `bootstrap5`...

```
use common\widgets\Alert;
use yii\bootstrap5\Breadcrumbs;
use yii\bootstrap5\Html;
use yii\bootstrap5\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap5\NavBar;

p2m\demo\assets\ThingsDemoAsset::register($this);
p2m\assets\BootstrapIconsAsset::register($this);
```

Giving exactly what I want...

```
<link href="/assets/ffcb6986/css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-tKLJeE1ALTUwtXlaGjJYM3sejfssWdAaWR2s97axw4xkiAdMzQjtOjgcyw0Y50KU" crossorigin="anonymous">

...

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/assets/b94ae250/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/ffcb6986/js/heroic-features.js"></script></body>
```

As soon as I add  anything `NavBar`, even entirely empty, to `frontend/views/layouts/main.php`...

```
    NavBar::begin();
    NavBar::end();
```

I get this output...

```
<link href="/assets/ffcb6986/css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-tKLJeE1ALTUwtXlaGjJYM3sejfssWdAaWR2s97axw4xkiAdMzQjtOjgcyw0Y50KU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="/assets/51c6396f/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- << this! -->

...

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/assets/b94ae250/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/ffcb6986/js/heroic-features.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/51c6396f/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script></body> <!-- << this! -->
```

`<!-- << this! -->` inserted to highlight the extra output.

What could be causing that extra Bootstrap to load?

Comment: Don't use bootstrap navbar it will internally register bootstrap plugin asset. [BootStrap Plugin Asset](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/caba7032f91acffdafb0f10dab150639803df667/src/NavBar.php#L155) You need to customize the navbar as well

Comment: @InsaneSkull I don't recall this being the case with earlier versions of Yii2, but no matter. I looked into the NavBar code & found a method that registers BootstrapAsset. Make an answer of your comment & I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use bootstrap navbar it will internally register bootstrap plugin asset. You need to customize the navbar as well.

[Yii2 Bootstrap NavrBar](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/caba7032f91acffdafb0f10dab150639803df667/src/NavBar.php#L155)

```
public function run()
{
    $tag = ArrayHelper::remove($this->containerOptions, 'tag', 'div');
    echo Html::endTag($tag);
    if ($this->renderInnerContainer) {
        echo Html::endTag('div');
    }
    $tag = ArrayHelper::remove($this->options, 'tag', 'nav');
    echo Html::endTag($tag);
    BootstrapPluginAsset::register($this->getView());
}
```

Comment: Looking deeper I've found I need to customise the Nav widget as well. Thank you.

Comment: It turns out there's a bunch of Bootstrap 5 components that need to be customised when using custom Bootstrap.

Comment: @Pedro Yes, You need to else use [Yii2 Bootstrap 5 extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap5)

Comment: Turns out that once you're using CDNs &/or custom Bootstrap 5 components, so many classes need overriding that one might as well make a custom version of the entire Yii Bootstrap 5 extension, which is what I've now done.